# Tensorflow + Keras CPU Utilization Question

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, openshift, cpu

A data science team is using Keras to train a model using Sequential. They want me to give them a GPU so they can speed up their model training, because they estimate it will take an obscenely long time to train using the current infra (like 6 months). The issue is that when I look at the CPU utilization of their model training, they max out around 50% CPU utilization. I ran their model on each size instance, and did see 100% CPU utilization until the largest size (32 core) where it only reaches 50%. Apart from that issue, we can't really give them a GPU, at least not anytime soon--so best to help them with their model if I can.

From what I understand, you can tell TF to limit number of cores used, or limit the number of parallelized threads it's using, but without those customizations, it will utilize all the resources it can, i.e. close to 100% of the CPU cores available.

Anyone have any insight why the CPU utilization would be 100% for smaller instances but not for the largest one? Anything I'm not thinking of? Any guidance or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

To add context, the code runs on a JupyterLab container in Openshift.

Comment: Very basic performance theory, if a component has utilization < 100%, its because some other component is the bottleneck.

Comment: You could try the [TensorFlow Profiler](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_profiling_keras)